# htaccess rewrite rule variable is not supported

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with a rewrite rule on php, I want it to be:

```
localhost/myproject/XXXX => localhost/myproject/index.php?request=XXXX

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I activated mod_rewrite on apache and my index.php is under WAMPDIR\www\MyProject

When I test it here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/
I get this:
[image]

Please help, thanks

Comment: The .htaccess is located on the same folder as index.php (WAMPDIR\www\MyProject) and when I test it on a browser or using Postman I get a not found error: `The requested URL /myproject/xxx was not found on this server.`

Comment: It shows a 500 internal error, so nothing wrong with the file, I think the problem comes from the rule.

Comment: `localhost/myproject/index.php?request=XXXX` works fine but I want to access it this way: `localhost/myproject/XXXX` through rewriting the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have this code in `/myproject/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

There should not be a leading slash right after `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Works like a charm :) I surrounded it with `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c></IfModule>` Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You really don't have to make it that complicated.

This should suffice:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject/
RewriteRule ^/(.+) /myproject/index.php?request=$1 [L]
```

I strongly recommend that you read more about htaccess. It's really not that complicated even though it might look like it.

Comment: I'm sorry it doesn't work: `The requested URL /incommmobilews/xxx was not found on this server.`